# Taking audio uri from intent

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, uri

I'm stuck, and I can't manage to find a solution to it :/

What I'm doing is an app of sounds effects with sounds preloaded and choosen by the user, so I have default buttons with default sounds and the possibility of adding (as many as you want) buttons with sounds choosen by you.
So here's my part of code of the add-button:

```
public void add (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select music"));

}
```

The output should be an uri and I need to get that (I'll use it to take the path of the file choosen by the user), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I understood :)

For those who are trying to find a solution to that as me:
You don't have to use `startActivity()` but `startActivityForResult()` and then use the `getData()` method on the `intent` `parameter` of the `onActivityResult()` callback.

Here's the guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html